# Ubuntu Encrypted instalation in external Hard Drive booting in recovery shell "GNU Grub"

Tags: boot, encryption

What I did:

- 1 - Copied Ubuntu Studio 22.04.2 LTS to a Ventoy Pendrive
- 2 - Chosed Try or    install Ubuntu
- 3 - Clicked in the icon for install in the desktop
- 4 - During installation, Set the    language to Brazilian Portuguese and default keyboard
- 5 - Selected    Full instalation erasing disk (An external HD)
- 6- Flicked the    encrypted checkbox
- 7 - Chosed a phrase password
- 8 - Removed the    instalation media and reboot after the instalation
- 9- During the    boot, I enter the password for encryption
- 10 - It boots into GNU    grub, where I can see partitions like:
  (hd0), (hd0,gpt2), (hd1),    (hd1,gpt4)

When I hit the command "boot" from the gnu grub, it'll say that I need to load a kernel first.

I made a fresh install repeating the exact same process, and the result was the same.

Note that if I make the exact same process but don't encrypt it, it will works.

Comment: Being specific as to your *native* language can help, as when your install the system your *live* system was operational & may have thus used different native keyboard mapping which the OS had control over at install time (*ie. key you used for full disk encryption*), however at decryption time there is no OS running so your machine *firmware* controls keyboard & key entry (*thus maybe using English/French/Chinese or a different language to that used at install; brand/model specific as managed by firmware*).  Your *unstated* release (inc. point release) matters here, and you gave no details.

Comment: @guiverc, sorry, I made some changes in the question to be more clear, as I've made some mistakes before

Comment: I'll provide https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions and suggest you scroll down to "*PASSPHRASE CHARACTER SET:*" and read that section; as the 'passphrase' used at install time MUST MATCH what your machine will allow you to enter at unlock time (*keyboard being OS controlled at install time, firmware controlled at boot*).  Sorry I'm a *dumb aussie* and have no experience here, but you need to use keys that are the same when OS is running & what your *firmware* allows as I understand it (*but my understanding is limited here sorry!*)

Comment: (my last comment is my understanding of this bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-meta/+bug/1827501  ... Lubuntu & Ubuntu Studio share the `calamares` installer, which is what is involved here... installer & the *full disk encryption* that Lubuntu/Ubuntu.Studio use that means little is available before providing the key & access to encrypted disk is possible!)

Comment: FYI:  What you're experiencing is what is expected WHEN you enter an *incorrect* passphrase to decrypt.  Your 'entry of keys' as understood by your machine *firmware* at decryption time does not match your 'entry of keys' at install time as understood by the running OS & `calamares` at encryption time.  The *gitlab.wiki* link I provided I believe is your answer UNLESS you made a typo when attempting to decrypt your system at reboot (*or install time*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll provide https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions and suggest you scroll down to

"***PASSPHRASE CHARACTER SET:***"

and read that section; as the 'passphrase' used at install time MUST MATCH what your machine will allow you to enter at unlock time (*keyboard being OS controlled at install time, firmware controlled at boot*).

This is my understanding of this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-meta/+bug/1827501).  Lubuntu & Ubuntu Studio share the `calamares` installer, which is what is involved here, or really the installer **plus** the *full disk encryption* that Lubuntu/Ubuntu.Studio use that means little is available on your disk before providing the key & access to encrypted disk is possible!

What you're experiencing is what is expected WHEN you enter an *incorrect* passphrase to decrypt.  Your 'entry of keys' as understood by your machine *firmware* at decryption time does not match your 'entry of keys' at install time as understood by the running OS & `calamares` at encryption time.

The *gitlab.wiki* link I provided I believe is your answer UNLESS you made a typo when attempting to decrypt your system at reboot (*or install time*).

*Sorry I'm a *dumb aussie* and have no experience here (using *english* which is identical to the firmware of the systems I use), but you need to use keys that are the same when OS is running & what your firmware allows as I understand it.*

Comment: Thanks! I've made a new installation using common characters for the password, and it works now!